# Merging two arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays

Write a method

```
public static ArrayList merge(ArrayList a, ArrayList b)
```

that merges two array lists, alternating elements from both array lists. If one array list is shorter than the other, then alternate as long as you can and then append the remaining elements from the longer array list. For example, if a is

```
     1 4 9 16
```

and `b` is

```
      9 7 4 9 11
```

then merge returns the array list

```
      1 9 4 7 9 4 16 9 11
```

What I tried doing was writing a for loop with if statements such that a number is added to the merge array list from array list a when i is an even number (i%2==0) and from array list b when i is an odd number. I am however not sure how to deal with the fact that one array list can be longer than the other. Could anyone please help me out?here is my code so far

```
package test;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Arraybig {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int m = scan.nextInt();
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        int[] A = new int[m];

        for (int k = 0; k < m; k++) {
            A[k] = scan.nextInt();
        }

        int[] B = new int[n];

        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
            B[k] = scan.nextInt();
        }

        int[] C = new int[m + n];
        int max = Math.max(m, n);
        int a = 0, b = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < m+n; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0 && a < A.length) {
                C[i] = A[a];
                a++;
            } else if (i % 2 != 0 && b < B.length) {
                C[i] = B[b];
                b++;
            } else if (a < A.length) {
                C[i] = A[a];
                a++;
            } else {
                C[i] = B[b];
                b++;
            }
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < C.length; j++) {
            System.out.println(C[j] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem? I think your code works fine!

Comment: @AliAmiri  when the input is like this 5 8 
1 2 3 4 5 
6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13    the output is 
1 
6 
2 
7 
3 
8 
4 
9 
0 
0 
0 
0 
0

Comment: Did you test your code on two lists of equal length? Did it work correctly? Can you see why not?

Comment: @arne.b i tested it and it did not work and i have no idea why

Answer (score 1):

A more cleaner approach can be something like this..

```
list<Integer> a1=//1st list
list<Integer> a2=//2nd list
list<Integer> a3=new Arraylist<Integer>();


int length=(a1.size()<=a2.size())?a1.size():a2.size();

for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
        a3.add(a1.get(i));
        a3.add(a2.get(i));
}
for(int i=length;i<a1.size();i++){
    a3.add(a1.get(i));
}
for(int i=length;i<a2.size();i++){
    a3.add(a2.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hint: How long is the array you want to fill? And how many iterations does your main `for` loop run? Why is it not the same number?